# Asking for a tool in an ecosystem of one language that exists in an ecosystem of another language

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, recommendation-questions

My recent question "[A command line tool to create a C++ project from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70550930/a-command-line-tool-to-create-a-c-project-from-scratch)" was closed with the following comment:

> We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations.

I tend to agree with the reason given, because I was indeed asking for an advice on a tool:

> A new Rust project can be initialised with the [`cargo new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-03-hello-cargo.html#creating-a-project-with-cargo) command. It creates a new directory for the project, a configuration file, a `src/` directory with a `main.rs` file, and initialises a new Git repository along with a `.gitignore` file.
>
> Is there a similar command line tool that could create a C++ project and accompanying files from scratch?

When I was asking that, my reasoning was the following:

1. That is something that exists in the ecosystem of one language; is there something similar in the ecosystem of another language (regardless of the build system)?
2. If that functionality does not exist in C++, could my question inspire someone to implement that? (e.g., as a CMake feature)

How would you advise to ask these type of questions about one's experience in an ecosystem of one language projected to an ecosystem of another language? How to ask such question so that the SO guidelines are not violated and/or the community of SO users benefit.

Comment: *"questions about one's experience in an ecosystem of one language projected to an ecosystem of another language?"* - You didn't ask about one's experience though, you asked for a tool. Either way, my answer would likely be.... "Ask elsewhere"

Comment: There are plenty of tools that exist for one language and not for others. Often, but not always, the most well used or respected languages have the most "toys" as the company that owns the language has the resource (and money) to fund the tools or the greater community is large enough that 3rd parties build them (sometimes also at a high cost to use as well). You need to look for those though, as [main] isn't a recommendation service. As for the latter question, you might inspire someone with such a question, but then I doubt it would really happen on one person's desire.

Comment: "How would you advise to ask these types of questions about one's experience in an ecosystem of one language projected to an ecosystem of another language?" - To put it simply.  You don't ask this type of question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: *"could my question inspire someone to implement that? (e.g., as a CMake feature)"* - Not very likely. The true trigger for someone creating something is necessity; they don't have it and they need it, but cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a separate site for tool recommendations that this question would probably work better on.

In terms of the reasons for the request:

> That is something that exists in the ecosystem of one language; is there something similar in the ecosystem of another language (regardless of the build system)?

The mere fact that it exists in another ecosystem doesn't really solve the main problem with this type of request: the fact that they tend to attract low-quality answers, such as spam, unsubstantiated opinions, and link-only answers.

> If that functionality does not exist in C++, could my question inspire someone to implement that? (e.g., as a CMake feature)

That's really not what Stack Overflow is for - it's exclusively for practical, answerable programming questions, *not* for veiled feature or product development requests.